# Filtering Oracle 11g Hierarchical Tables

Tags: sql, oracle11g, hierarchy

I am having some trouble understanding when filtering is applied to an Oracle hierarchical table.

I basically have a table that uses a `EMP / MGR` structure using a query like:

```
start with mgr is null
connect by nocycle prior emp = mgr;
```

Within this same table, I have an additional column that specifies the `DATE_OF_BIRTH` of the  employee.

Based on this scenario and keeping to the same hierarchical nature of this table/query, how would I apply a filter to say only display hierarchical data where the `DATE_OF_BIRTH` is between 1965 and 1980?

Would this just be a normal WHERE condition before the START WITH clause or does this need to be part of the `START WITH / CONNECT By clause`

```
where date_of_birth between 1965 and 1980 
start with mgr is null
connect by nocycle prior emp = mgr;
```

Comment: I would suggest trying both ways on your data to see which returns the results you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF55328) is fairly explicit on this point:

> Oracle processes hierarchical queries as follows:
>
> - A join, if present, is evaluated first, whether the join is specified in the FROM clause or with WHERE clause predicates.
> - The CONNECT BY condition is evaluated.
> - Any remaining WHERE clause predicates are evaluated.

How you use this information depends on how you want your hierarchy to be calculated. If you want to use all managers and employees to create the tree and then filter out the people you don't want to display you're doing it correctly at the moment.

If you want to ensure that those with a date of birth without that date range are excluded from the hierarchy calculation then you'd have to filter in a sub-query first.

```
 select ...
   from ( select ... from ... where year_of_birth not between 1965 and 1980 )
  start with mgr is null
connect by nocycle prior emp = mgr;
```